# Providing alias for eclipse does not work

Tags: alias

I tried to open my `bashrc` and tried to provide an alias for eclipse like

```
alias eclipse='bash /usr/local/softy/eclipse/eclipse'
```

But I get the following error when I try to invoke eclipse.

```
/usr/local/softy/eclipse/eclipse: /usr/local/softy/eclipse/eclipse: cannot execute binary file
```

Its permission is

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 messagebus users 71023 Feb  8  2012 /usr/local/softy/eclipse/eclipse
```

And I am able to open it directly from terminal like `/usr/local/softy/eclipse/eclipse`

How should I correct it?

Comment: Could you add the output of `ls -l /usr/local/softy/eclipse/eclipse`?  Also does it work running `/usr/local/softy/eclipse/eclipse` directly in terminal.

Comment: @Sneetsher I have edited the query. Have included what you asked.

Answer (score 0):

Remove 'bash' and make direct call:

```
alias eclipse='/usr/local/softy/eclipse/eclipse'
```

If there are other tools in that folder, You may want to add that folder directly to system PATH:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/softy/eclipse
```